# Why does the Entity Framework's DbContext.Find() generate a query with select top 2?

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework-4.1

Why does the Entity Framework's DbContext.Find() generate a query with select top 2 and a derived table?  By definition, the query is looking up by primary key which should be unique.

Comment: I got freaked out on this observation today :) Glad that you have already posted this :P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Find` checks first if the entity with the given key is already in the context. If not it queries the database. Possibly it uses in this case a LINQ query using `SingleOrDefault`. `SingleOrDefault` translates to `SELECT TOP 2` to be able to throw an exception if the result has more than one entity.

So, why doesn't `Find` use `FirstOrDefault` (which would translate to `SELECT TOP 1`). I don't know, but I would guess that `Find` wants to check that the entity is really unique in the database. It should - because it's the primary key the query uses - but model and database could be out of sync because someone changed the primary key in the database, for example: added a column to a composite key in the database but not in the model.

Really just a hypothesis. Only EF development team probably can answer what's exactly the reason.

**Edit**

If I do this as described above (add column to composite key in DB and add a record with the same value in the first key column) and call then `Find`, I get the exception...

> Sequence contains more than one element

...and this stacktrace:

```
//...
System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindInStore(
    WrappedEntityKey key, String keyValuesParamName)
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
```

So, it looks that `Find` indeed uses `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: When I run SingleOrDefault through LinqPad and VS I never get SELECT TOP 2. Where are you getting that from? Is that specific to EF?

Comment: @JamieRRytlewski: It's the case in EF, yes. I'm not sure if it's exclusive to EF. What did you test? With LINQ to SQL?

Comment: Yes I used Linq to Sql....so it must be a difference. I was doing some reading and it appears as though it's only showing up with EF. It makes sense to have the TOP2, I just never saw it as I don't use EF.

Comment: That is what I concluded.  Make sure its unique, but without bringing back the entire kitchen sink.  So "TOP 2" makes sense, but I'm with the OP, it looks weird when you see it.