# Entity Framework generates inefficient select when using Find()

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am noticing that the Entity Framework is generated some inefficient queries when using the `Find()` method. For example here is my C# code.

```
Model model = unit.Repository.DbSet.Find(model.ID);
```

**Generate Find() Query**

```
DECLARE @p0 int = 1

SELECT 
[Limit1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Limit1].[UserID] AS [UserID], 
[Limit1].[Started] AS [Started], 
[Limit1].[Updated] AS [Updated], 
[Limit1].[Completed] AS [Completed]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (2) 
        [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
        [Extent1].[UserID] AS [UserID], 
        [Extent1].[Started] AS [Started], 
        [Extent1].[Updated] AS [Updated], 
        [Extent1].[Completed] AS [Completed]
        FROM [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @p0
)  AS [Limit1]
```

It seems to be running a whole other select query which is unnecessary. Here is the output using the `SingleOrDefault()` method.

**Generate SingleOrDefault() Query**

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 int = 1

SELECT TOP (2) 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[UserID] AS [UserID], 
[Extent1].[Started] AS [Started], 
[Extent1].[Updated] AS [Updated], 
[Extent1].[Completed] AS [Completed]
FROM [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @p__linq__0
```

Is there a reason why `Find()` is generating two selects? Should the `Find()` method be avoided in favor of the `SingleOrDefault()` method?

Comment: How did you measure that the query is inefficient? Perhaps query execution engine in SQL server will optimize it.

Comment: This question could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822877/why-does-the-entity-frameworks-dbcontext-find-generate-a-query-with-select-to

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I am using the MiniProfiler for ASP MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there is any performance difference between the two, for sql server at least.  It looks like the first one just has an extra wrapper around the select.  Running a similar query on a database that I have generates the exact same plan, so I would imagine the outer select gets optimized away in the execution plan.

Comment: Yea you are right. I am just worried that when the queries get more complex (like including multiply navigation properties) that it might slow down.

Comment: I'm not too knowledgeable on Entity framework itself, but the docs say this: " If the entity is not in the context then a query will be executed and evaluated against the data in the data source".  Which would mean to me that the difference between Find and SingleOrDefault is that Find wouldn't hit the database if it's in the context where SingleOrDefault would always hit the database.  So from a  performance aspect, Find could be quicker if you've already retrieved it in the current context.

Comment: @Sbossb: `Find` will never load navigation properties. It just looks for a single record. Anyway EF produces strange queries but that is a cost of using it. Either you like the abstraction it provides and you are ready to pay the cost or you can get back to hand written queries.